# Common way to call mother-class operator= in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, conversion-operator

Let's suppose I have a class Dog that inherits from class Animal,
you might want to insert a call to Animal::operator= in Dog::operator=.

What is the most readable/common way to write it?

I think I know those two...

```
static_cast<Animal*>(this)->operator=(other);
```

and

```
this->Animal::operator=(other);
```

Comment: In the second case, `this->` is superfluous; `Animal::operator=(other);` is enough.

Comment: Also, the first case can be made to look a bit more "natural", as `*static_cast<Animal*>(this) = other;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are doing it from within a child class method

```
Animal::operator=(other);
```

No need for `this->`. The scope resolution syntax does exactly what was requested. I don't see a point in doing it "indirectly" with a cast.

Note also that doing it with a cast might not produce the expected result in general case, since it will not disable the dynamic resolution of *virtual* method call. (And, BTW, assignment operator can be declared virtual). An obvious consequence of that is that with virtual methods the "cast" variant might easily result in endless recursion.

Comment: In fact, it probably *should* be virtual if you're overriding it in a derived class: you're almost certainly going to get unwanted behavior at some point.

Comment: @mos: Usually, when someone is talking about "assignment operator", they mean the copy-assignment operator. Copy-assignment operators don't override each other in the hierarchy since their signatures are different from class to class (different parameter types). So, your reasoning does not apply to copy-assignment operator. It might not apply to any assignment operator, because it is a special member function with its own rules.

Comment: @mos: ... But in general case the danger is there, even with assignment operators.

Comment: Correct one: no need for `this` unless `Animal` is a template.

Comment: @Pavel Shved: Err... Not sure what you mean (I could be missing something). `this->` with templates is used to force lookup of an *unqualified* name in dependent base type. Alternative approach is to use a *qualified* name. In this case we already have a qualified name. What would be the point of adding `this->`?

Answer (score 6):

`this->Animal::operator=(other);` is the correct way, you fully qualify the method referring to your parent implementation, you don't need to cast yourself for that and it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Alexandrescu would also use: `Animal& me = *this; me = other;`. I am not sure I understand the exact purpose of this though, but it is clean and produces (as far as I can tell) the same effect.

Comment: As @AndreyT said, you have the danger of operator= being virtual, you could end in endless recursion, apart from not having called the method you wanted.

Comment: ... except that this "Alexandrescu" variant might also lead to infinite recursion in case of virtual assigment operators. Yes, I know that a virtual assigment operator is not exactly something that one sees very often (if at all), but as a generic method (i.e. not for assignment operators only) this is seriously broken.